# Save my currently opened tab as "HTML Only" IE

Tags: powershell, explorer

I open my web page with IE. It opens the authentication page.
After putting my user and pass, I copy the URL and use the PS command to download the content, but it downloads the authentication page.
Is there a way how to get the source code of my already opened page?

```
#(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Outfile $Path).Content
```

Comment: Do you know how web authorizations work? About the cookies, and session data?